# Warnings in MLP model(Caret, RSNNS package)

Tags: r, neural-network, r-caret

I was running a Multiple Layer Perception model via caret package in R. The code is:

```
LR_fitcontrol <- trainControl(method='cv',
                              number=2,
                              classProbs = T,
                              summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                              savePredictions = T)
Sys.time()

para.grid <-data.frame(size= c(10))
KNN_fit <- train(LR_formula_tune,data=model_data_Classification,
                 method="mlp",
                 metric='ROC',
                 preProc = c('center','scale'),
                 tuneGrid = para.grid,
                 trControl= LR_fitcontrol
)
```

the warnings I got.

```
1: In snnsObject$setUnitName(num, iNames[[i]]) :
  SNNS error message in setUnitName : SNNS-Kernel Error: Symbol pattern invalid (must match [A-Za-z][^|, ]*)
```

There are 16 warnings like it.

I've run many other models on this dataset via caret, like RF, KNN, Logistic, Naive Bayes. So the dataset is fine I suppose.

And of course, I googled this error and no similar results at all. I think some help is needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. As the warning tells you there is some problem with the used symbols. In my case it was a factor-level named '03Prüfen'. To avoid the warning I changed the factor-level to '03Pruefen', which fixed the problem. So you should avoid special characters like 'äöü' and so on. Check your data for those. As I have no idea what your data looks like I can't tell you where exactly your problem is.

Working example:

```
library(caret)
library(RSNNS)
data(iris) #load example-data
iris$ExampleFeature <- as.factor(c(rep("01Blümchen", 50), rep("02Blume", 50), rep("03Blöme", 50))) #add factor with problematic factor level names

# Define trainControl #
control <- trainControl(method='cv',
                        number=2,
                        classProbs = TRUE,
                        savePredictions = "final")

# Start training which will create warnings #
KNN_fit <- train(Species~.,
                 data=iris,
                 method="mlp",
                 metric='Accuracy',
                 preProc=c('center','scale'),
                 trControl=control
)

# Change factor level names and re-run training #
levels(iris$ExampleFeature) <- c("01Bluemchen","02Blume","03Bloeme")

KNN_fit <- train(Species~.,
                 data=iris,
                 method="mlp",
                 metric='Accuracy',
                 preProc=c('center','scale'),
                 trControl=control
)
```

In addition: The warning does not occure when I'm running the code on my Windows-laptop with RStudio. It only occures on my RStudio-Server running on CentOS.

Comment: I get this result from Mac system, so maybe it’s sth platform dependent.

Comment: Might be. Are there any special characters in your variable-names or in any factor-levels? If so, change it and try again. Let me know if it works for you.